# LightTable creates connection per file

Tags: clojure, lighttable

How can I tell LightTable which connection to use to evaluate code?
Before latest version, it created one connection upon first evaluation and then used the connection for all subsequent evals. Now it creates connection per file I evaluate form in + if I launch instarepl, it creates also new connection for it too :(

If I use remote repl, it connects to the repl successfully, but still creates new connections for each clojure file(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, deleting all LightTable's settings (~/.config/LightTable folder on debian) helped.

Comment: I've never encountered this and, if deleting your local user data fixed it for you, I'm not sure anyone could reproduce this either.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't say what versions represented the 'before' and 'after'.

If you've moved to LightTable 0.8.x then you should update the Clojure Plugin to 0.3.2. which fixes this problem as described in the [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/LightTable/Clojure/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

Comment: Note: LightTable needs a restart after updating the Clojure Plugin